# 2-wire analog buffers

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

[image: 2 wire analog buffers]
How do these 2-wire analog buffers work? The one on the left is driving a current sink and the negative supply is hooked up to the output. The one on the right is a current source driver and the positive supply is hooked up to the output.

I'm trying to wrap my head around why the rails are able to be hooked up to the output and still work...I can't figure out how to factor in the current source/sink into the circuit.

Comment: It works as a voltage follower but it can only sink/source current in one direction. Also the amp must allow the input voltage near (and slightly outside) the rail.

Answer (score 1):

They work because the power to run the op-amp is coming from the courrent-source that's connected to the output.

For correct operation the op-amp must allow the input voltage to touch the positive or negative supply rail, and the current source mus provide sufficient current.

With this setup you are also constrained to using only single device packages.

Take for example the LM321 an inexpensive single op-amp derived from the earlier LM324 quad op-amp. This device allows the input voltage to go slightly below the negative supply, so it's a good candidate for first diagram.

In this setup the one of the output transistors is shorted C to E by the V- to Out connection and so does not not participate, but the other can source current from V+ to drive current into the current-sink.

[image: taken from the TI data sheet]

with the output connected to the negative supply (ground symbol) the section shaded in red turns off and plays no part, but the rest of the op-amp continues to function, the voltage at point 'A' is 1.2V above the negative supply allowing the rest of the op-amp to function.

Comment: I imagine with this setup, the output voltage won't be quite as close to the input voltage as it would be versus a buffer with +- rails. Unless it's a true rail-to-rail op-amp?

Comment: rail-to rail output is not needed,  the output will be very close to the input so long as the input is such enough that the op-amp gets enough voltage from the current source to operate.